# Loading a WebUserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to Load a WebUserControl that has a session id such as:

```
string loadURL = "/CPCLeadScrubExceptions.ascx?&SessionID=" + SessionId;
Control control = LoadControl(loadURL);
holder.Controls.Add(control);
```

When I do this I get the following error: "The virtual path '/CPCLeadScrubExceptions.ascx?&SessionID=a545a9e1-4085-419b-aff0-1a27a76d01e4' maps to another application, which is not allowed."

Comment: Why are you including the SessionID? Why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is very clear.  You're trying to load `/CPCLeadScrubExceptions.ascx`, which maps to another application.

E.g. your app is `http://mydomain.com/myapp/Something.aspx` so you can't access anything not under the `/myapp/` path.  You need to correct your path to be relative (first try without the '/' perhaps).

Edit: `LoadControl` takes a control path, not a request URL with query string.  ASP.NET uses the parameter to locate the control to load, it doesn't issue a request itself, therefore doesn't need the SessionID.

Comment: It works when I don't have the SessionId in it. The error only appears when the SessionID is added.

Comment: Can you confirm it's only the SessionID you remove, and not the "/" (maybe post the first line when it definitely works)?  It seems very unlikely, but you may be right

Comment: If I use: "CPCLeadScrubExceptions.ascx"; it works. If I use "CPCLeadScrubExceptions.ascx?&SessionID" + SessionId;" it says it cant find the file.

Comment: Sounds like you solved it yourself :) I have offered some explanation in my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

The path you're supplying is not a virtual path (they start with `~/`)

Plus the session id shouldn't be in the virtual path (you're not doing a request here), you could set it after you created the control like
`control.SessionID = SessionId`

Answer (score 0):

If the control is in the same application you are calling it from, have you tried using:

```
string loadURL = "~/CPCLeadScrubExceptions.ascx?&SessionID=" + SessionId;
```

(Note the `~` sign.)